# AdMob 4.3.1 adds not showing up (No AdMob ID yet (just for test), can't get ViewWidth)

Tags: android, google-play, admob

First of all, I know there are a lot of questions about this topic. I searched all over the internet, but most of the tutorials are about older versions of AdMob.  Also, all have some kind of different solution for the problem. They all do not work for me. I am very very close to getting these test adds into my application. They just don't show up. I get the following errors:

> 02-21 21:05:46.457: W/webcore(14924): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
>
> 02-21 21:05:46.586: W/Ads(14924): Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?
>
> 02-21 21:05:46.586: D/webviewglue(14924): nativeDestroy view: 0x685300
>
> 02-21 21:05:46.586: I/Ads(14924): onFailedToReceiveAd(Invalid Google Ad request.)

I do not have a AdMob publisher ID yet, since this will be my first APP for the market (and I first have to have an APP on the market before I get an ID for the APP). What ID should I use? Currently I have (testing on my Android Phone):

```
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice("9B08CXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    //adRequest.addTestDevice("037c7xxxxxxxxxxx"); (Not right, is from console)
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

In my XML, I have (because it also warns about viewWidth?). It is packed in a bigger LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="50dip">

<com.google.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_pub_id"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope the question is small enough, but still contains enough information.

Thanks in advance!
Kinds regards,
Jos.

**EDIT:** I do have the manifest file changed (add permissions, activity android:name=...,
    android:configChanges=...). I added the jar to a lib-folder and added it to the libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to have an app already on the market to get a Publisher ID for a new app.  In the Android Package URL field that's on the "Add Site/App" form, just enter "market://details?id=your.package.name".  You'll of course want to replace the 'your.package.name' with your app's actual package name.

The viewWidth warnings are fine and you will likely still see them after inserting your Publisher ID.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Have no time right now, but will try this soon and get back to you!

Comment: +1. You can leave the market url blank and fill it in later when your app goes live.

Comment: It works! I have so often switched between my emulator and my real phone, that I forgot to switch off my Ad-block software on my phone. I feel like such a retard. One more question: If I were to post my code online: Should I remove the adRequest.addTestDevice("9B08CXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); line? Or can I keep it so I won't make money from myself pressing the adds (and eventually getting blocked by AdMob?).

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the following errors:

```
07-26 15:51:24.046: W/webcore(842): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout  
07-26 15:51:24.871: W/Ads(842): Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine request type.
```

Is your ad unit id correct?