# can't see admob banners in libgdx app

Tags: android, admob, libgdx

I added the code as it is written 
[here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx)

But I can't see banners with ads in my game.
My app is published. But the current version is not published yet.
I've  added to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

There is a similar thread
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384487/admob-4-3-1-adds-not-showing-up-no-admob-id-yet-just-for-test-cant-get-view)

But I could not understand the answer there.
They wrote:
  ***You don't need to have an app already on the market to get a Publisher ID for a new app.
  In the Android Package URL field that's on the "Add Site/App" form, just enter
  "market://details?id=your.package.name". You'll of course want to replace the 
  'your.package.name' with your app's actual package name.
  The viewWidth warnings are fine and you will likely still see them after inserting 
  your Publisher ID.***

I don't understand where should I include "market://details?id=your.package.name".

Logcat shows me the following errors:
***w/Ads (3200) Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine request type.
Is your ad unit id correct?
w/webcore(3200): can't get the viewwidth after the first layout***

My publisher key is correctly inserted to the code.
BTW it was printed in logcat. (Is it possible to exclude printing it?)

Thanks

Comment: if you want this question to get answered, you'd better show your layout (where you embedded adview) and your code where you create adview and request an ad from the admob server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You don't need to have an app already on the market to get a Publisher
>   ID for a new app. In the Android Package URL field that's on the "Add
>   Site/App" form, just enter "market://details?id=your.package.name".
>   You'll of course want to replace the 'your.package.name' with your
>   app's actual package name. The viewWidth warnings are fine and you
>   will likely still see them after inserting your Publisher ID.

This is related to Admob, when adding an application to Admob (via admob.com) its not required to have the app published in the market. Admob will ask you for the package name, its ok to write a package name that is not yet published in the Android Market.

Comment: I added my app to admob.com. But still can't see banners. Maybe I have to wait a few hours? I see the same errors in logcat on the device

Comment: It works after I replaced my google publisher key to admob publisher ID. In mentioned above example code it was written "insert your secret key", instead of "insert your admob publisher ID". That was the cause. But I see the only banner, no new ads. I did set my app setting in admob to change ads.