# Invalid Ad request when calling DoubleClick for Publishers with AdMob SDK

Tags: android, admob, google-dfp

I am using Admob SDK to load banner ads from DFP on Android.

I am using the XML method as defined in this page to load up the ads: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/fundamentals

When I run the apps, I get

```
06-21 16:44:30.354: I/Ads(2641): onFailedToReceiveAd(Invalid Ad request.)
```

When I change to testing mode by

```
adRequest.addTestDevice("xxx");
```

Then I can see the Google Test banner successfully. So assume my SDK integration is correct, what the heck if the "Invalid Ad request"?

Comment: What ad unit ID are you using? `Invalid Ad Request` means the SDK couldn't interpret your ad unit ID correctly. Do you have any spaces in your ad unit? When you set test mode, the SDK fetches an AdMob test ad and doesn't go through DFP backend, so that's why test mode may work.

Comment: Post some code, need some more information...

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag, the adUnitId is given my client, but there is no space when I use them. I just download the sample project from Google and replace by this ID: http://google-mobile-dev.googlecode.com/files/DFP_BannerExample_iOS_1.3.zip. Are there any thing need to be set from the DFP platform?

Comment: @MattCooper, just download the sample project from Google and replace the `kSampleAdUnitID` with my ID can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Is your adUnitId in the form of  `/networkCode/adUnitName`, for example `/6253334/dfp_example_ad`?

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag, Yes it is. Will it be due to configuration issue in DFP side? Becuase when I use the sample `kSampleAdUnitID` in the sample project, it is working (not test mode)

Comment: The error means the ad unit ID is invalid. When the SDK tries to query DFP with that ad unit, that ad unit doesn't exist. Could be the client gave you the wrong ad unit ID. Make sure they tell you the right network code, and the right name of the ad unit. If the client is using DFP Premium, the ad unit could be hierarchical as well. So it could be something like `/12345/a/b/c/your_ad_unit`.

Answer (score 1):

Your ad unit is most likely invalid. You need to get access to the DFP account you are using and make sure that the network ID, ad unit name and dimensions are correct. There could be no matching ads or anything could be going on really... but like you say the test ad works so it is most probably something setup wrong within DFP.

I usually work with DFP on websites so things may be slightly different with the Admob SDK but if it is any help I have this little tool I use to test my DFP ad delivery:

http://coop182.github.io/jquery.dfp.js/dfptests/test.html?google_console=1&networkID=15572793&adunitID=Leader&dimensions=728x90

you can also press CTRL+F10 to bring up the DFP web console and get some more information on the delivery of the ad... but like I said this might not be that much help because it is an Admob ad... but worth a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Form another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384487/admob-4-3-1-adds-not-showing-up-no-admob-id-yet-just-for-test-cant-get-view) :

You don't need to have an app already on the market to get a Publisher ID for a new app. In the Android Package URL field that's on the "Add Site/App" form, just enter "market://details?id=your.package.name". You'll of course want to replace the 'your.package.name' with your app's actual package name.

The viewWidth warnings are fine and you will likely still see them after inserting your Publisher ID.

EDIT: There's a nice suggestion [here](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=3689) too.