# Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine request type. Is this ad unit id correct?

Tags: java, android, admob

After updating to "new abMob", it appears to have this problem...
use this code, but nothing displays:

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

and got warning:

> Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine request type. Is your
>   ad unit id correct?

What's wrong?
Using android emulator, admob 6.4.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The adUnit Ids in the new Admob console are of the form:

> ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYYY

This is what your problem is.
Go check your Admob console and update your app to reflect that.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, the ad unit id was incorrect in AdMob app management section! There was a `~` instead of `/` in the id. I fixed it by viewing the GoogleService info plist and found the correct unit id.

Change:

```
ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX
```

to:

```
ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = " ca-app-pub-8572140050384888/1853336688 "; //no spaces are allowed before and after admob-id..
```

Change to :
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-8572140050384888/1853336688";

[android](/questions/tagged/android) [java](/questions/tagged/java) [admob](/questions/tagged/admob)[unity](/questions/tagged/unity)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to go to www.admob.com. There sign in with your account. Then klick at "Monetize" next to "Home". There you have to add your app and set the settings for your advertisement. After that, the website is asking you to send you an e-mail with your ad unit id, you have to put in your strings.xml file instead of the exsample id. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have an app already on the market to get a Publisher ID for a new app. In the Android Package URL field that's on the "Add Site/App" form, just enter "market://details?id=your.package.name". You'll of course want to replace the 'your.package.name' with your app's actual package name.

The viewWidth warnings are fine and you will likely still see them after inserting your Publisher ID.

Refer below links..

[How to get Google's example code working for AdMob 4.1.0 using an Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389156/how-to-get-googles-example-code-working-for-admob-4-1-0-using-an-android-device)

[AdMob 4.3.1 adds not showing up (No AdMob ID yet (just for test), can't get ViewWidth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384487/admob-4-3-1-adds-not-showing-up-no-admob-id-yet-just-for-test-cant-get-view)

Comment: I had an app in marked and all was fine with "old admob" (i used publisher id like "a-xxxxxxxxxxx")... this problem appears after i upgaded my admob account to new version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format

```
GADBannerView * bannerView_;

bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

bannerView_.adUnitID=@"ca-app-pub-5250422073333775/6825580043";  //Id for Top Banners

bannerView_.rootViewController = self;

[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```