# android admob not display any add although configure all needed settings

Tags: android, admob

Hello all I am creating an app in that I need to add ad-mob banner for that I get ca-app-pub-00000000000000/000000000 like this key.
My logcat is saying:

> 05-26 05:56:21.241: W/Ads(1803): Invalid unknown request error: Cannot
>   determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?

(My key  code replaced by 0)
Now I am putting this (
with is same unit id my full screen add is loading successfully(InterstitialAd ) )

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-00000000000000/000000000/>//puted here my key
```

In my manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

But still it not display any add
What is wrong I have done?
can anybody suggest me the solution?

With is same unit id my full screen add is loading successfully - InterstitialAd

Comment: Is their any margin for the layout that you add this adview???

Comment: no i have not puted any margin

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line to your main layout and remove from AdView

```
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

May be it helps.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should specify location for it

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

and put this line into the main layout as Prateek said

`xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`

Comment: is there any view near above ad? if yes, you put this line into it `android:layout_above="@id/ad"`

Comment: have you seen my edited que? ID is ok? it loding full screen add from same ID

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to have an app already on the market to get a Publisher ID for a new app. In the Android Package URL field that’s on the “Add Site/App” form, just enter “market://details?id=your.package.name”. You’ll of course want to replace the ‘your.package.name’ with your app’s actual package name.

The viewWidth warnings are fine and you will likely still see them after inserting your Publisher ID.

Refer below links..

[How to get Google's example code working for AdMob 4.1.0 using an Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389156/how-to-get-googles-example-code-working-for-admob-4-1-0-using-an-android-device)

[AdMob 4.3.1 adds not showing up (No AdMob ID yet (just for test), can't get ViewWidth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384487/admob-4-3-1-adds-not-showing-up-no-admob-id-yet-just-for-test-cant-get-view)

Comment: i am not totally understanding but using the same key i am getting full screen add how it possible?

Comment: my mean to say full screen add InterstitialAd (using same ID i ma getting InterstitialAd)

Answer (score 0):

You should have different AdUnitIds for banner and for interstitial. Trying to use an insterstitial id in a banner ad could well be your problem.

Create a separate banner adUnit in the Admob dashboard and use that.